# PHP Birthday notification for today and tomorow

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code for showing notification for Birthday of my users for today and tomorow and i don't know how to make this to show me that today is user A birthday and tomorow is user B birthday. See the code below, thanks for help

Php Code:

```
 <?php
    echo"<div class='remindbox'>";
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'pass');
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `mls_users` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`birthdate`, '%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(`birthdate`, '%m%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%m%d') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`birthdate`, '%m%d') ASC";

    // proces for birthday
    if($sql1) {
         $userz = $conn->query($sql1);
    foreach ($userz as $row) {   
        $username = $row['username'];
        $birthdate= $row['birthdate'];


     if($row['username'] == 'me') {
     echo '<div id="Modal" class="remind img-balon"> <img src="img/bday.png" width="18">&nbsp;Today is my Birthday!</div>';
} else {
    echo '<div id="Modal" class="remind img-balon"> <img src="img/bday.png" width="18">&nbsp;Today is '.$username.' Birthday</div>';
} 
    }  
         }

    ?>
```

Comment: You have $usernames and $birthdate from the table row. You need to check if $birthdate is today's date. If it is today's date then the birthday is today. If not, the birthdate is tomorrow (assuming you only check today & tomorrow).

Comment: hmm, can u show me an example please?

Comment: Well, assuming your dates are stored YYYY-MM-DD you would check against today: if (date('m-d') == substr($birthdate,5))  { // you found a birthday that is today }